In the TurtleBot3 Gazebo simulation, the angular velocity exhibits significant fluctuations at certain points, leading to instability
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Gazebo 11.11 to simulate the TurtleBot 3 Waffle Pi robot. I modified the .gazebo.xacro file because the default settings result in significant slipping, especially at higher speeds (e.g., vx = 1.0, w = 1.0, which are not considered excessively fast).
Then I encountered the issue depicted in the image below, where the angular velocity is unstable and exhibits significant spikes. How should I adjust the parameters in the .gazebo.xacro file to address this problem? maxVel, minDepth seems to have no effect on this issue. So it maybe other params like kp, kd...

Here is the edited .gazebo.xacro file: (original file can be seen at turtlebot3)
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="turtlebot3_waffle_pi_sim" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <xacro:arg name="laser_visual"  default="false"/>
  <xacro:arg name="camera_visual" default="false"/>
  <xacro:arg name="imu_visual"    default="false"/>

  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <material>Gazebo/DarkGrey</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="wheel_left_link">
    <mu1>1.0</mu1>
    <mu2>1.0</mu2>
    <soft_cfm>0.0</soft_cfm>
    <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
    <kp>1e15</kp>
    <kd>4e12</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <maxVel>10</maxVel>
    <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="wheel_right_link">
    <mu1>1.0</mu1>
    <mu2>1.0</mu2>
    <soft_cfm>0.0</soft_cfm>
    <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
    <kp>1e15</kp>
    <kd>4e12</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <maxVel>10</maxVel>
    <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="caster_back_right_link">
    <mu1>0.01</mu1>
    <mu2>0.01</mu2>
    <soft_cfm>0.0</soft_cfm>
    <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
    <kp>1e15</kp>
    <kd>4e12</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <maxVel>10</maxVel>
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="caster_back_left_link">
    <mu1>0.01</mu1>
    <mu2>0.01</mu2>
    <soft_cfm>0.0</soft_cfm>
    <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
    <kp>1e15</kp>
    <kd>4e12</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <maxVel>10</maxVel>
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="imu_link">
    <sensor type="imu" name="imu">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>$(arg imu_visual)</visualize>
    </sensor>
    <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="turtlebot3_waffle_pi_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
      <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
      <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
      <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
      <odometrySource>world</odometrySource>
      <publishOdomTF>true</publishOdomTF>
      <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
      <publishWheelTF>false</publishWheelTF>
      <publishTf>true</publishTf>
      <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
      <legacyMode>false</legacyMode>
      <updateRate>100</updateRate>
      <leftJoint>wheel_left_joint</leftJoint>
      <rightJoint>wheel_right_joint</rightJoint>
      <wheelSeparation>0.287</wheelSeparation>
      <wheelDiameter>0.066</wheelDiameter>
      <wheelAcceleration>4</wheelAcceleration>
      <wheelTorque>10</wheelTorque>
      <rosDebugLevel>na</rosDebugLevel>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="imu_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_imu.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
      <frameName>imu_link</frameName>
      <topicName>imu</topicName>
      <serviceName>imu_service</serviceName>
      <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
      <updateRate>0</updateRate>
      <imu>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <rate>
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
            <bias_mean>0.0000075</bias_mean>
            <bias_stddev>0.0000008</bias_stddev>
          </rate>
          <accel>
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>1.7e-2</stddev>
            <bias_mean>0.1</bias_mean>
            <bias_stddev>0.001</bias_stddev>
          </accel>
        </noise>
      </imu>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="base_scan">
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
    <sensor type="ray" name="lds_lfcd_sensor">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>$(arg laser_visual)</visualize>
      <update_rate>5</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>360</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>0.0</min_angle>
            <max_angle>6.28319</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.120</min>
          <max>3.5</max>
          <resolution>0.015</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.01</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="gazebo_ros_lds_lfcd_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
        <topicName>scan</topicName>
        <frameName>base_scan</frameName>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

<!--link : https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/-->
  <gazebo reference="camera_rgb_frame">
    <sensor type="camera" name="Pi Camera">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>$(arg camera_visual)</visualize>
      <camera>
          <horizontal_fov>1.085595</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
              <width>640</width>
              <height>480</height>
              <format>R8G8B8</format>
          </image>
          <clip>
              <near>0.03</near>
              <far>100</far>
          </clip>
      </camera>
      <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>30.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>camera</cameraName>
        <frameName>camera_rgb_optical_frame</frameName>
        <imageTopicName>rgb/image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>rgb/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
        <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

</robot>

Thanks for any reply！！

I'd start with upgrading to Gazebo 11 which is the default (and supported) version for 20.04. Also make sure you pull Gazebo from the packages.osrfoundation.org APT repo and not from packages.ros.org, which contains outdated versions of Gazebo.

@MartinPecka I made a mistake, my gazebo version is 11:
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.11.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Current Gazebo 11 version is 11.14. So you have an old version. Please, follow the Gazebo installation tutorial to get the latest version (especially the section on adding the additional PPA).

@MartinPecka, I upgrade to 11.14, it does not solve the problem. The robot's odometry data, as shown in the picture above, exhibits significant noise, with some fluctuations so large that they can't even be classified as mere noise.
